# Can InDesign CS6 automatically update figure and step numbers for consumer instruction revisions?

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, layout

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

I'm creating consumer instructions with many steps and associated graphics with corresponding figure numbers. For example, Step 6 refers to the graphic labeled Figure 6, etc.

My question is, when I have to add or delete a step in the future, can I make ID automatically update both the step and figure numbers to accommodate the change?

I'm working with Photoshop CS6 and placing graphics into ID--perhaps using a layer for the Figure numbers would be helpful?

I'm after something like what MS Word does when modifying bulleted and number lists.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the list numbering feature:

Paragraph Palette | fly-out menu | Bullets and Numbering...

List Type: Numbers

Create as many lists as are needed --- the rules for them re-setting takes some fiddling, but you can usually work things out.

You can also import a Word document w/ lists and use its paragraph styles.